# <function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'const boost::filesystem::path::value_type *' to 'std::string'

Tags: c++, boost

```
void loadImages(const string& src, vector<string> &dest){

directory_iterator end;

path dir(src);

string filename;
int n = 0;
int num;

for (directory_iterator pos(dir); pos != end; ++pos) {
    if (is_regular_file(*pos)) {
        n++;
    }
}

dest.resize(n);

for (directory_iterator pos(dir); pos != end; ++pos) {
    if (is_regular_file(*pos)) {
        filename = pos->path().filename().string();
        num = atoi((filename.substr(0, filename.find("."))).c_str());
        dest[num - 1] = pos->path().string();
    }
}
```

}

how can i solve this error plus there are 2 errors: E0308   more than one instance of overloaded function "is_regular_file" matches the argument list:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMa8y.png)

Comment: Try `is_regular_file(pos->path())`

Comment: what type is `dest[]`?

Comment: Why do you not use directly the method `string()`: `dest[num - 1] = pos->path().string();`

Comment: Even what you use after, `auto entry_name = pos->path().string()` and use it for `regular_file`, `dest[]`

Comment: directory iterator does not dereference. But as you have done, it has a member `path`. `pos->path()` And you don't have to find the dot. [There are members](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#path-decomposition) and operators like `stem`, `extension`. Read through the doc if you are going to us filesystem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you copy pasted the entire error output.

Comment: Are you using Windows? I think c_str() returns wchar_t* for Windows.

Comment: @zett42  is_regular_file(pos->path()) gave 2 more errors of illegal indirection

Comment: @buratino i posted image containing the code and all errors in it . i tried this also `is_regular_file(pos->path())` but gave 2 errors

Comment: @aeroyorch i edited the post and now u can see it full  ...plz make changes in the code as you think and post it whole plz

Comment: @aeroyorch your changes were made into code and that solved the error thank so much <3 <3